# sqlalchemyを用いて、カラムの値を文字列リスト内の文字列に制限する方法

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

## やりたいこと

標題通り、あるテーブルのカラムの値を特定の文字列だけ許可するようにsqlalchemyで記述するにはどのようにすれば良いでしょうか？
insert/updateされたときに、文字列に合致しない場合にはエラーとして処理して、受け付けないようにしたいです。

## 環境

Python 3.9
Windows10

```py
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import Column, String
from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql import INTEGER

# このリストの値に制限したい
mode_type_list = [
    'DEFAULT',
    'RIGHT',
    'LEFT',
    'CENTER'
]


Base = declarative_base()
RDB_PATH = 'sqlite:///db.sqlite3'
ECHO_LOG = True

engine = create_engine(
    RDB_PATH, echo=ECHO_LOG
)

class Test(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'test_tbl'
    key = Column(
        'pkey',
        INTEGER(unsigned=True),
        primary_key=True,
        autoincrement=True,
    )
    key = Column('mode_type', String(256))

    def __init__(self,mode_type:str):
        self.mode_type = mode_type

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

param = Test(mode_type='DEFAULT')
session.add(param)

session.commit()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

enum使うとよいかも

定義部分で Pythonの `enum` と sqlalchemyの `Enum` を指定し, `enum.Enum` でクラスを作成
(必要であれば, `value` を文字列で指定も可能 … 詳しくは [enum --- 列挙型のサポート](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/enum.html))

```py
import enum

from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, String, Enum   # ⇐ Enum を追加

# このリストの値に制限したい
mode_type_list = [
    'DEFAULT',
    'RIGHT',
    'LEFT',
    'CENTER'
]
ModeType = enum.Enum('ModeType', mode_type_list)
```

`ModeType` の要素(？) の確認

```py
In [3]: [e for e in ModeType]
Out[3]:
[<ModeType.DEFAULT: 1>,
 <ModeType.RIGHT: 2>,
 <ModeType.LEFT: 3>,
 <ModeType.CENTER: 4>]
```

カラム指定とデータ追加の部分

`ModeType`を文字列で指定するなら `ModeType['DEFAULT']` で可能
`ModeType.DEFAULT == ModeType['DEFAULT']` で同じものを指します

```py
class Test(Base):

    # カラム指定
    mode_type = Column('mode_type', Enum(ModeType))

with Session() as session, session.begin():
    param = Test(mode_type=ModeType.DEFAULT)   # 文字列でなら ModeType['DEFAULT']
    session.add(param)
```

---

##### (追記)実行結果など

実行すると, ログに以下の内容が出るはずで `VARCHAR(7)`として扱われる模様

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_tbl (
    pkey INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    mode_type VARCHAR(7), 
    PRIMARY KEY (pkey)
)
```

内容の確認

```py
from sqlalchemy import text
with Session() as session:
    result = session.execute(text('SELECT * FROM test_tbl'))
    for row in result:
        print(row)
# (1, 'DEFAULT')
```